# Error in ADS OleDB when inserting data into VFP Database?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro, advantage-database-server

I need some help with the ADS OleDB Provider for Visual FoxPro.

I'm trying to insert data from an 64-Bit .net-Application into a FoxPro Database. The table in which the data will be inserted has about 130'000 records, 139 fields and 11 indexes. Every time I run my sample application i get an error which says that the indexes are corrupted after only 3 or 4 inserted records.

If I use a smaller table to insert some sample data there is no problem with corrupted indexes.

Does someone know this problem and has found out a way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?  Is there an error number?  Error text?

Comment: Hi Mark!

I get the error with the Number 7200. Here you can find a Screenshot of the Message: http://img293.imageshack.us/i/unbenanntkf.jpg/

Comment: What is your connection string?

Answer (score 1):

VFP doesn't support 64-bit --- PERIOD...  However, why not use the direct VFP OleDb provider. I've used it for years and haven't really encountered any issues with all types of queries, insert, updates, deletes, and even ExecuteScript() calls.

Clarification...

Have you tried using VFP's OleDB provider instead of ADS?  I'm sure it still has similar objects derived from similar interface objects such as...

```
Ole Db Object    Common interface
---------------- -----------------
OleDbConnection  IDbConnection
OleDbParameter   IDbDataParameter
OleDbCommand     IDbCommand
OleDbDataAdapter IDbDataAdapter
OleDbException   IDbException
```

Comment: I know that VFP doesn't support 64-Bit. But it runs on 64-Bit Systems. You can use the VFP OleDb provider only with aplications which are build as 32-bit. But I have a 64-Bit Application which needs access to the VFP DB and its not possible to rebuild it as 32-Bit!

Comment: @FoxProGuy, revised answer about common interface via VFP OleDb. have you tried working with that?